# standardizing CSV file types

Tags: php, excel, csv

I'm using a csv parser class (http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/) to parse and extract data from csv files.  The problem I'm encountering is that it only works for certain csv file types.  (It seems that there is a csv type for Mac, for Ms-Dos, and for Windows.)

The code works if I use a csv file which was saved on a mac (in excel) using the csv - windows option.  However, if I save a file on a windows machine simply as csv, that doesn't work. (You would think that that would be the same format as saving csv-windows on a mac.) It does work from a windows machine if I save it as a csv-MSDOS file.  This seems a little ridiculous.

Is there a way to standardize these three file types so that my code can read any type of csv that is uploaded?

i'm thinking it would be something like this:

```
$standardizedCSV = preg_replace_all('/\r[^\n]/', '\r\n', $csvContent);
```

I know it has something to do with how each file type handles end of lines, but I'm a little put out trying to figure out those differences.  If anybody has any advice, please let me know.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
This is the relevant code from the csv parser I'm using which extracts data row by row:

```
$c = 0;
$d = $this->settings['delimiter'];
$e = $this->settings['escape'];
$l = $this->settings['length'];

$res = fopen($this->_filename, 'r');

while ($keys = fgetcsv($res, $l, $d, $e)) {

if ($c == 0) {
   $this->headers = $keys;
} else {
   array_push($this->rows, $keys);
}

$c ++;
}
```

I guess I need to understand how fgetcsv handles eol's, so that I can make sure that csv files of any format are handled in the same manner.

Comment: UPDATE I'm adding the relevant code from the csv parser to my original post so that you can see how it handles EOL's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

The problem was with line endings, but I didn't need to create my own EOL parser.  This runtime setting does it for me.  See http://us.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the line endings is an issue. The thing about CSV is that it's only a "comma separated values" file and not standardized beyond that. So some systems separate the values using commas, some using semicolons (`;`). I'm sure there are variations that use even other value separators.

Additionally, the escape character (most often backslash `\`) can be different between CSV files, and some CSV files also use quotation marks around each value (`"`).

A CSV file can use any variation between the above. For instance, I'm fairly certain that Microsoft Excel exports CSV files separating values using semicolons and without any quotation around the values.

I'm sure there are ways to auto-detect how to parse the CSV file, but the best way would be allowing the user to decide. That's what Excel does.

Comment: The reason I believe that EOL's are the issue is that when my parser runs through a non-compliant cvs type (mentioned above), the $csvparser->headers variable records the entire file - it doesn't just record the fields for the first row.  Compliant csv types very neatly store headers in $this->headers and the data rows in $this->rows. So, somehow the EOLs for some file types cause the while loop to iterate, and others do not.

Comment: Also - when I look at a compliant and non-compliant csv file type side-by-side in a text editor, they appear exactly identical with commas separating the values.  (I'm using BBEdit to do this.)  The only difference between the two is that BBEdit indicates that the compliant version is in 'Windows (CRLF)' format - (that's in a dropdown at the bottom of the BBEdit window.  I can't 'see' the EOLs however..

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSV files, you have to agree on many details which are not properly standardized:

- Line endings (Unix 0x0a, Macintosh 0x0d, DOS 0x0d 0x0a)
- Field separators (comma, semicolon etc.)
- Field quoting (all fields quoted, only string fields, only string fields containing field and line separators)
- Escaping of double quotes within string fields (doubling of double quotes, backslash character before double quote etc.)
- Multiline string fields (are they allowed or not)
- File encoding (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 etc.)

If you create a CSV reader, you can automatically handle different variations of line endings and field quoting. But the rest has to be known to the CSV parser beforehand.

The defacto standard is the CSV format produced by Excel. However, Excel uses different variations of the format:

- Usually DOS line endings (but I've never tried it with Excel for Macintosh)
- Field separator depending on the locale. If the comma is used to group the digits in long numbers, Excel uses the semicolon as field separator. Otherwise the comma.
- Excel uses double quotes if needed.
- Excel doubles the double quotes within string fields.
- Excel supports multiline string fields.
- The file encoding seems to be the file encoding of the current locale. So it varies.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response.  I did standardize the line-endings to conform to the DOS format - 0x0d 0x0a - which worked for one file, but not for another.  I didn't look to see if that file may have been non-compliant in a different way.  -It may have used colons instead of commas to delineate info for example. I'll look at that in the morning, and report back.  Thanks a lot.